A certain wordpress function would keep redirecting me to 404
I have these two functions:
Function 1: Runs relatively quick considering it fetches and loops through third-party API responses, about a minute
function update_thirdparty1_hook() {
    check_admin_referer( 'thirdparty1' );
    update_thirdparty1();
    wp_redirect( admin_url('admin.php?page=theme-panel') );
    exit;
}

Function 2: Runs slower, it fetches and loops through more third-party API responses, about 5 minutes
function update_thirdparty2_hook() {
    check_admin_referer( 'thirdparty2' );
    update_thirdparty2();
    wp_redirect( admin_url('admin.php?page=theme-panel') );
    exit;
}

Both functions are hooked to admin_post_ (admin_post_thirdparty1, admin_post_thirdparty2 respectively). Both of the functions inside only contains loops that create/update posts of certain custom post types and sometimes delete.
For some reason, Function 2 would show me a 404 page but the URL shows /wp-admin/admin-post.php
I cannot figure out where the issue is.
PS: I have confirmed that the inner function is working, because it is creating the post that it's supposed to, but for some reason after it does that instead of redirecting to the page it was from, it redirects to a 404 page whereas function 1 works perfectly fine.
Also all this code works fine in local, it the redirect only fails when it's uploaded in the cpanel server.

I'd start by looking at what's happening on the network level, using your browser dev tools. What redirects are actually happening; are you getting an actual HTTP status code 404, or is perhaps just the page content saying "404" for some reason; is anything going wrong with additional AJAX requests in the background, ...

Yes it's status 404, sorry I should have mentioned I did look at that to investigate the Location header but it's not there
